# How to run a requestAnimationFrame animation for a certain duration?

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I have the following function that scrolls some elements "up" out of view by adjusting their style every "tick":

```
const incr = 1;
let moved = 0;

function changeHeight( children, duration, setTop) {
  // duration = 1500
  const height = children.clientHeight; // in this case, 166px

  let moved = 0; 
  const slideUp = function (timestamp) {
    // we're done if the amount moved is larger than height
    if ( moved < height ) { 
      children.style.top = `${ setTop( moved, height ) }px`;
      moved = moved + incr // move by some amount

      requestAnimationFrame(slideUp) 

    } else {
      // reset
      moved = 0;
    }
  };

  // start sliding
  slideUp();
}
```

If `requestAnimationFrame` triggers roughly every 16ms or so, I would like to use `duration` to dictate how long the animation will be running for, so the formula seems to be `height * 16.5 / duration`

I'm confused by `requestAnimationFrame` - why is the time per tick not constant? I'd like to use `timestamp` that's generated by `requestAnimationFrame` but the first few cycles take *much* longer than the average of ~16.5

Is the 16.5 going to look different on a different machine or screen?

How do I make the height change take exactly the amount of time specified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is called delta-time.
The formula is `Math.min((now - start) / duration, 1) * final_amount`.

Using this delta-time, you don't need to care at which frequency your interval fires, every step is rendered "where it should be".

As for your questions,

> why is the time per tick not constant

Certainly because the browser has a lot of things to do during the first frames and couldn't do everything in the 16.7ms frame. It will thus move your callback to be executed a bit later, and may even skip frames if under too much pressure.

> Is the 16.5 going to look different on a different machine or screen?

Yes, `requestAnimationFrame` will basically try to follow the monitor's refresh rate. So on a 60Hz monitor you'll indeed have 16.7ms per frame, but on a 120Hz monitor you'd have only half of it.

> How do I make the height change take exactly the amount of time specified?

Use a delta-time:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("div");
let moved = 0;
changeHeight(elem, 200, 5000);

function changeHeight(elem, height, duration) {
  const start = performance.now();
  const step = function () {
    const now = performance.now();
    const delta = Math.min((now - start) / duration, 1);
    elem.style.height = (delta * height) + "px";
    if (delta < 1) {
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };
  step();
}
```

```css
div { width: 50px; background: green; }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. `requestAnimationFrame` was quite confusing, appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Follow-up to this... if the element in question has children of its own, suppose I want to be able to roll/unroll it - how would you go about retaining the original height so that it also "unrolls" to the correct height?

Comment: You could store it in a js variable, or even in the element's `.dataset`