# Refreshing canvas with 'setInterval()' function fails with Firefox, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, setinterval

I am working in a web game in html/javascript using canvas, defining some framerate `fr` with `canvas.internal = setInternal(drawCanvas, 1000/fr)` where `drawCanvas` is the function drawing all images at each frame.

It works fine for most of the browsers, but it fails miserably with any flavor of Firefox, somehow.

I can reproduce the issue with the snippet below. It just shows a white box when it works, but it randomly flashes with Firefox. I am also adding a video comparing Firefox and Chrome.

I have been searching for an answer and asking in my circle, but I also failed miserably there (just as Firefox refreshing the canvas with my code).

Any clue of why does it flashes with Firefox and how to prevent it?

[canvas flashing in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHeBo.gif)

```js
    // square of 100x100 pixels, all white, in the desired format
    var whiteSquare = {'I': 0, 'J': 0, 'DI': 100, 'DJ': 100, 'png': Array(100*100*4).fill(255)}

    // Get elements from html: canvas and context   ;
    var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");      
    
    // Initiate loop (reload every 15ms)
    canvas.interval = setInterval(drawCanvas, 1000/15);
    
    // Function in the loop: drawing images
    function drawCanvas(t) {
    
        // clean canvas
        context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
        var img = whiteSquare;
        // draw image at canvas from a 1D array containing RGBA pixels
        var tile = context.createImageData(img['DI'],img['DJ']);
        for (var k=0; k<img['png'].length; k+=4){
            var ki = Math.floor(k/4)%(img['DI']);
            var kj = Math.floor(Math.floor(k/4)/(img['DI']));
            var kk = (Math.floor(kj)*img['DI'] + Math.floor(ki))*4;
            tile.data[k  ] = img.png[kk  ];
            tile.data[k+1] = img.png[kk+1];
            tile.data[k+2] = img.png[kk+2];
            tile.data[k+3] = img.png[kk+3];
        }
        createImageBitmap(tile).then(item => context.drawImage(item,0,0));
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CANVAS TEST</title>
<style>
    canvas {
        image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
        image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
        image-rendering: pixelated;
        image-rendering: crisp-edges;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>

</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<canvas id="canvas" width = "100" height = "100" ></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `1000/15` will set the timer up for 66ms intervals, not 15ms.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the behavior, but is there a reason for using `setInterval` rather than `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: 66ms? got it, I thought it was the other way around, thanks!

Comment: I'm using `setInterval` because it's the one I knew. I will try `requestAnimationFrame` instead, I just need how to use it thanks!

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I put this link here about `setInterval` VS `requestAnimationFrame` in case it's also useful for others  https://riptutorial.com/html5-canvas/example/16985/use-requestanimationframe---not-setinterval---for-animation-loops

Answer (score 0):

The animation flickers because [`createImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) is (supposed to be) asynchronous.

Since you do clear the canvas in one task and then draw the bitmap in another one, there is a very high chance that the canvas gets painted to screen before the bitmap got drawn to it, meaning that a blank canvas has been painted.

This doesn't occur in Chromium based browsers because there `createImageBitmap` will do its job asynchronously only when the source image is a Blob, for all other sources, they do the decoding + rendering synchronously and thus the bitmap is rendered in the next microtask, with no risk of having the painting to screen occur in between.

So, you need to first create your ImageBitmap and then, once it's ready to perform all the drawings on your context. This can probably be handled in many ways, but one option would be to render the bitmap one frame in advance:

```js
// square of 100x100 pixels, all white, in the desired format
var whiteSquare = {
  'I': 0,
  'J': 0,
  'DI': 100,
  'DJ': 100,
  'png': Array(100 * 100 * 4).fill(255)
}

// Get elements from html: canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create your ImageData only once
// We'll reuse the same at every frame
var tile = context.createImageData(whiteSquare['DI'], whiteSquare['DJ']);

// We declare a variable to hold our ImageBitmap
let bitmap;

// Initiate loop (reload every 66.6ms)
canvas.interval = setInterval(drawCanvas, 1000 / 15);

// Function in the loop: draw the bitmap if available and generate the next frame's one
function drawCanvas(t) {
  if (bitmap) {
    // clean canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    bitmap.close(); // free the memory
    bitmap = null; // no need to render the same frame
  }
  var img = whiteSquare;
  // draw image at canvas from a 1D array containing RGBA pixels
  for (var k = 0; k < img['png'].length; k += 4) {
    var ki = Math.floor(k / 4) % (img['DI']);
    var kj = Math.floor(Math.floor(k / 4) / (img['DI']));
    var kk = (Math.floor(kj) * img['DI'] + Math.floor(ki)) * 4;
    tile.data[k] = img.png[kk];
    tile.data[k + 1] = img.png[kk + 1];
    tile.data[k + 2] = img.png[kk + 2];
    tile.data[k + 3] = img.png[kk + 3];
  }
  createImageBitmap(tile).then(item => bitmap = item);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CANVAS TEST</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

*(Note that I did move your ImageData declaration outside of the animation loop, no need to allocate all this memory every frame, reuse this kind objects.)*

Now, if you are really only using `createImageBitmap` with this ImageData as source, and that you really are drawing that bitmap on a cleared canvas, then don't even use an ImageBitmap here, that's overkill. Instead simply [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) that ImageData. This method is synchronous, and doesn't imply copying the bitmap data anywhere else than on the context's buffer.

```js
// square of 100x100 pixels, all white, in the desired format
var whiteSquare = {
  'I': 0,
  'J': 0,
  'DI': 100,
  'DJ': 100,
  'png': Array(100 * 100 * 4).fill(255)
}

// Get elements from html: canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create your ImageData only once
// We'll reuse the same at every frame
var tile = context.createImageData(whiteSquare['DI'], whiteSquare['DJ']);

// We declare a variable to hold our ImageBitmap
let bitmap;

// Initiate loop (reload every 66.6ms)
canvas.interval = setInterval(drawCanvas, 1000 / 15);

// Function in the loop: draw the bitmap if available and generate the next frame's one
function drawCanvas(t) {
  var img = whiteSquare;
  // draw image at canvas from a 1D array containing RGBA pixels
  for (var k = 0; k < img['png'].length; k += 4) {
    var ki = Math.floor(k / 4) % (img['DI']);
    var kj = Math.floor(Math.floor(k / 4) / (img['DI']));
    var kk = (Math.floor(kj) * img['DI'] + Math.floor(ki)) * 4;
    tile.data[k] = img.png[kk];
    tile.data[k + 1] = img.png[kk + 1];
    tile.data[k + 2] = img.png[kk + 2];
    tile.data[k + 3] = img.png[kk + 3];
  }
  // We don't even need to clear the context
  // because putImageData will make the transparent pixels from the ImageData
  // actually transparent on the context.
  context.putImageData(tile, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CANVAS TEST</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

And finally, note that using `setInterval` for an animation is rarely the correct move.
Here it's quite unclear what frequency you were trying to achieve but the best is generally to base your animation on the monitor's refresh rate, because otherwise your drawings may never come to the screen, or on the contrary you may have full painting frames with nothing updated, or even both situations if you're too close to the refresh-rate.
To avoid this, it's better to use `requestAnimationFrame` which will schedule a callback to fire right before the browser will send the new graphics in the renderer's pipes, ensuring that your animation is synchronized with the monitor.

However note that this method will fire at different rates on different devices, and so the best is to use a delta time to make your animation rate-agnostic. You can see an example of that in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256093/how-to-run-a-requestanimationframe-animation-for-a-certain-duration/70256517#70256517), but failing to see clearly what your animation is about, I can't really provide an out of the box solution for you.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for the insights!!